# Is it possible to ignore column when using "Match"?

Tags: sqlite

According to [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3) I can write:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'title:linux problems';
```

Where title is a column name. Is it possible to create something like:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'ignore:linux problems';
```

To search in all table excluding the linux column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search only in one column or in all columns.

You could try to list all columns except the one you want to ignore:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'col1:linux OR col2:linux OR ...'
```

Comment: I know about this way. But if i have 20 or 100 columns (i know that it's not good for db, but still)..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NOT to exclude a column, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'linux problems' NOT ignorecolumnname:'linux problems';
```

This will match everything but the ignored (NOT) column.

EDIT: apparently this is driver dependent, it works on some but not all.